# For each real number $m$, we say that a subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is linearly $M$

Tags: geometry

For each real number $m$, we say that a subset $B$ of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is linearly $M$ iff $$\forall (x,y) \in B, y = mx$$

So now the question asked me to give a geometric description of the above set and prove it...

So I am not sure if this is obvious, but isn't $B$ just the set of all lines passing through the origin, with each different $m$, you have a different gradient..

I am not too sure how to "prove it". To me $$B = \{(x,y) \in \mathbf{R} \times \mathbf{R}~|~ y = mx, m \in \mathbf{R}\}$$

Comment: This property also holds of any subset of the points on the line through the origin of gradient $m$.  To prove that, follow the standard approach to proving $B \subseteq \{ ... \mid ...\}$.

Comment: Hi! I thought B is already defined as the set notation I wrote above. Or do I need to prove it

Comment: Your set notation is a good description of the line (and I don't think it needs proof). But the property on $B$ says that every element of $B$ is on the line (by an extremely easy proof taking your set notation as the definition of the line). The property doesn't say that every point on the line is on $B$.